# Passing JWT token in the header of werkzeug test_client get method

Tags: python, flask, jwt, werkzeug

I am currently writing unit tests for my Flask REST API. The endpoint I am testing requires a token which I successfully fetch from another endpoint. When passing this token to the `test_client.get()` method, I get an error that I can't solve.

Here is the code of my unit test:

```py
def test_get_all_users(self):
        # encoding credentials of a user inserted in setup method of test class
        credentials = b64encode(b"user1@mail.com:1234").decode('utf-8')
        # fetch the token using test_client().get()
        # note: self.test_api is my werkzeug test_client() instantiated beforehand
        result = json.loads(self.test_api.get("/users/api/v1/token", headers={"Authorization": f"Basic {credentials}"}).data)
        # encode the token so I can pass it to the get method
        token_encoded = b64encode(bytes(result['token'], 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
        # error happens at the next line because of headers?
        result = json.loads(self.test_api.get("/users/api/v1/user", headers={"Authorization": f"JWT {token_encoded}"}).data)
        assert result.status_code == 200
        # ...
```

The code of the tested endpoint:

```py
@api.route("/users/api/v1/user", methods=['GET'])
@token_required
def get_all_users(token):
    """ Function for retrieving all users in db """
    # checking if current user role is valid
    output = []
    # fetching all users
    users = User.query.all()
    # building output dict
    for user in users:
        output.append(dict(user))
    return jsonify({'users' : output})
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
============================================================================= FAILURES ==============================================================================
____________________________________________________________________ TestUser.test_get_all_users ____________________________________________________________________

self = <api.tests.test_users.TestUser testMethod=test_get_all_users>

    def test_get_all_users(self):
        # nominal test
        credentials = b64encode(b"user1@mail.com:1234").decode('utf-8')
        result = json.loads(self.test_api.get("/users/api/v1/token", headers={"Authorization": f"Basic {credentials}"}).data)
        print(result['token'])
        #token_encoded = bytes(result['token'], 'utf-8')
        token_encoded = b64encode(bytes(result['token'], 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
        result = json.loads(self.test_api.get("/users/api/v1/user", headers={"Authorization": f"JWT {token_encoded}"}).data)
>       assert result.status_code == 200
E       AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'

api/tests/test_users.py:83: AttributeError
====================================================================== short test summary info ======================================================================
FAILED api/tests/test_users.py::TestUser::test_get_all_users - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in the headers of the get method because `result` seems to be empty. I tried a few different options such as 'x-access-token', 'X-Auth', etc.. but none seemed to work as I got the same error.

Do you guys have any idea about what's wrong in my code? Could someone give me the correct way of declaring a token in the headers of this get() method? I checked on the internet but couldn't find anything that worked for me...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kind of found a way to address my problem. I rewrote the endpoints using flask-jwt-extended module. It uses Bearer token headers so my tests are now easy to write and all passing!